# Поиск разных частей строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Приведу сильно упрощенный пример. Есть строка `str`, допустим:

```
user=123456(somelogin)
```

Нужно получить идентификатор пользователя и его логин. Сейчас сделал так:

```
String id = str.replaceAll(".*user=(\\d+).*", "$1");
String name = str.replaceAll(".*user=\\d+\\((.*)\\).*", "$1");
```

Есть ли универсальный способ сделать это в одно действие, объединив 2 регулярки?

Возможно, так же красиво, как в языках с поддержкой кортежей или деструктуризации, не получится, но меня устроит вариант применения регулярки `.*user=(\\d+)\\((.*)\\).*` и получения на выходе массива строк, где первый элемент - первая группа, а второй - вторая.

Comment: Лично я не вижу смысла усложнять всё регулярками и сделал бы обычным indexOf операциями, но если вы настаиваете... Смотрели в сторону Match/MatchResult?

Comment: @test123 Без регулярок никак. Как обычно случается, в реальной жизни все много сложнее, чем в моем простом примере)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться связкой [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) и [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Решение будет не в одну строку, но зато по нему будет понятно, что вы что-то ищете в строке, а не заменой занимаетесь:

```
String str = "user=123456(somelogin)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*=(\\d+)\\((.*)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches())
{
    String userId = matcher.group(1);
    String login = matcher.group(2);
}
```

---

Регулярное выражение рассчитано на представленный пример строки. Если строка, на самом деле, может варьироваться сильнее, то нужно скорректировать рег. выражение.
В частности, если в строке могут быть символы после логина (и закрывающей скобки), то нужно либо добавить `.*` в конец рег. выражения, либо отказаться от `.*` с обоих концов рег. выражения и метода [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) в пользу метода [find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

Comment: Спасибо. С регулярками у меня проблем не наблюдается. С джавой буксую пока иногда =)

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "user=123456(somelogin)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*user=(\\d+)\\((.*)\\).*").matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    // 123456
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));    // somelogin
}
```